Is 非吸 an abbreviation for 非法吸收公众存款?
https://tv.cctv.com/2024/07/21/VIDE9VZHM28q21cIG1Qpqvr5240721.shtml?spm=C31267.PdQGws28DOXv.E25JptH8Kkey.14, 19:08,  has 非吸额. User did not find it listed as a word in BKRS and had to search web for a possible meaning as 非法吸收公众存款(或者非法变相吸收公众存款)额.

Yes. 非吸罪 is 非法吸收公众存款罪.
Another similar example: 帮信罪 is 帮助信息网络犯罪活动罪.

I don't like this kind of extreme abbreviation. They all sound like obscure jargon
